# Cannot install VCS package successfully using pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, python-packaging

Have a package on github that I'm trying to install using pipenv.

I am attempting to install the package thusly:

```
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/arepo/atotallyworking-python-package.git@v1.0.0#egg=atotallyworking-python-package.git
```

To be clear, this package has no issues whatsoever when installed via `virtualenv` and `pip` using a `requirements.txt` file.

The package is added to the `Pipfile` with no issue the first time around.

Then when I go back and try and install the dependencies in the Pipfile file, say for example with a fresh clone of the project that includes the github package in the Pipfile like so:

```
atotallyworking-python-package = {editable = true,git = "https://github.com/arepot/atotallyworking-python-package.git",ref = "v1.0.0"}
```

It blows up with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>

main()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main

parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main

requirements_dir=requirements_dir,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve

req_dir=requirements_dir

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps

req_dir=req_dir,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps

resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 385, in resolve

results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 102, in resolve

has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round

for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 280, in _iter_dependencies

for dependency in self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq):

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies

legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies

results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs

results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one

abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 197, in _get_abstract_dist_for

req, self.require_hashes, self.use_user_site, self.finder,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 321, in prepare_editable_requirement

abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist

self.req.run_egg_info()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 474, in run_egg_info

command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess

% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))

pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/60/cbz9nv2s4tx9c380cl4mmw140000gq/T/tmpsc9waggasource/atotallyworking-python-package/

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>

main()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main

parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main

requirements_dir=requirements_dir,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve

req_dir=requirements_dir

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps

req_dir=req_dir,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps

resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 385, in resolve

results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 102, in resolve

has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round

for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 280, in _iter_dependencies

for dependency in self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq):

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies

legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies

results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs

results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one

abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 197, in _get_abstract_dist_for

req, self.require_hashes, self.use_user_site, self.finder,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 321, in prepare_editable_requirement

abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist

self.req.run_egg_info()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 474, in run_egg_info

command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess

% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))

pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/60/cbz9nv2s4tx9c380cl4mmw140000gq/T/tmpsc9waggasource/atotallyworking-python-package/
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly here or what does this stack trace indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I ran the following commands, this issue seemed to be resolved:

```
pipenv --skip-lock
pipenv lock
```

Then, when I went back with a fresh copy of the repo and reinstalled everything, it was fine, no issues with the VCS dependency when installing via `pipenv install`.